# Build natural numbers by uniquely using 1 to 5 and operators

Tags: number-theory

To teach my students to calculate in their head, I came up with a game:

You are given the numbers $1$ to $5$ and the operators $x+y,x-y,x\cdot y,\frac{x}{y},x^y$ and parantheses $(,)$.

Now for a given number $n$ your task is to find the combination of numbers and symbols, s.t. **each number is used at most once** and the result is $n$. The number of parantheses is not limited. For example
$$
37=(4+2)^{(5-3)}+1
$$

Its amazing how far you can go with only the numbers $1$ to $5$. I tried to analyse this game mathematically but didnt come very far. 
My question here is:

**For a given set of numbers $1$ to $k$, what is the highest number $N$, s.t. every $n<N$ is representable by the above rules?**

Here are my ideas how to tackle this problem:
 1. The numbers that are not easy to represent are primes as you first have to get near them and then use addition or subtraction. Thus, the distribution of primes could be used to find easy and hard spots.
 2. If you can build a number $n$ with less than all $k$ numbers, you directly cover a lot of adjacent numbers. E.g. using
$$ 4\cdot 5 \cdot 3=60$$
leads to
$$
\begin{align}
4\cdot 5\cdot 3-2-1&=57\\
4\cdot 5\cdot 3-2&=58\\
4\cdot 5\cdot 3-1&=59\\
4\cdot 5\cdot 3+1&=61\\
4\cdot 5\cdot 3+2&=62\\
4\cdot 5\cdot 3+2+1&=63
\end{align}
$$
which can cover hard numbers.
Maybe using these two facts can lead to tighter bounds.

Comment: Just an idea, number of such expressions is finite, so in principle you should be able to calculate upper bound for $N$ using combinatorics.

Comment: ...and since there's finite number of such expressions one can also walk through them and calculate their value...

Comment: Yes, of course. We wrote a script to find all combinations of possible numbers. But maybe someone from a number theory perspective has an idea to tackle this problem mathematically.

Comment: An easy upper bound for $N$ is $k \uparrow \uparrow k$ (Knuth notation)

Comment: I doubt there is a way to get exact $N$ by mathematics reasoning alone (not traversing all possibilities), sharpening the upper bound seems the best you can get imo. Of course, I'd be glad if someone can prove me wrong. Also another idea would be to calculate this number for few small $k$'s and try your luck on oeis.org.

Comment: $(2+1)\uparrow 3\uparrow 4\uparrow 5$ is the upper bound of all the combinations of numbers from $1$ to $5$.

Comment: @Nurator: Must all intermediate results be integers? Can intermediate results be negative or zero?

Comment: @quasi No, any intermediate result can be whatever you like, be it rational numbers, negative or zero. But you dont have to use every number each time, so zero should be not important.

Comment: @Nurator: Can you post the counts from your script for $k=4$ and $k=5$ (i.e., the number of distinct achievable values)?

Comment: @quasi I dont sure I know what you mean. The question is not how many different numbers are achievable. Instead, we want to find the highest number, s.t. every number below it can be achieved. I dont have the script on hand right now, but the numbers are approximately 50 for $k=4$ and 125 for $k=5$

Comment: @Nurator: I thought the problem was to count the number of possible results. Now I see that I misread the question. Sorry.

Comment: @Nurator: But there's still an issue. For large $k$, say $k=100$, it's conceivable that two very large power chains differ by a small value. In such a case, a script would be useless.

Comment: @Nurator: Also, do you expect your students to know how do deal with complex numbers? For example, what if you have an intermediate result such as
$$(5-6)^
{\left(
{\large{\frac{4-3}{2}}}
\right)
}
$$

Comment: @quasi When I play the game with students, I just give them one number $n$ to get to. They do all the computations they want in their head, noone every used complex numbers! I dont think this is feasible to get to a given number :D

Comment: @Nurator: In any case, my sense is that it's a fun question for the students, but not mathematically tractable for large $k$. With rules properly set to avoid non-real intermediate results or ridiculously large intermediate results, it makes for a challenging programming exercise.

Comment: @Nurator: When you get a chance, please update your post to show the results you obtained from your script for $1\le k\le 5$.

Comment: The problem is equivalent to finding the smallest positive integer that cannot be represented by the rules described.